# How to @mention an individual from a ServiceNow flow to MS Teams post/message?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, servicenow, mention

I have used ServiceNow's Flow Designer to create a flow to post a message to MS Teams using the webhook URL, however the message field does not allow me to use the "Assigned to" email data pill (value) to prefix it with an "@" so the individual assigned the ticket can be personally notified with the MS Teams @mentioning function.

I noticed that each of the fields in the "MS Teams Post a Message" action can be scripted, I am currently assuming that there will be some means of inserting a script(?) to prefix the message with the @mentioning I desire?

Has anyone else considered this, been successful?

Comment: Could you please confirm if this is what you are looking for?https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/quebec/app_store_learnv2_flowdesigner_quebec_flow_designer/app_store_learnv2_flowdesigner_quebec_notifications_in_flow_designer/app_store_learnv2_flowdesigner_quebec_exercise_send_a_notification

Comment: From what I read in the link, that is using the notification system within ServiceNow(?) for people logged in. What I am seeking is the ability to issue @mention notifications to MS Teams via the MS Team's Post a Message action using inline scripting.